# Jar file and Farsi font

Tags: java, fonts

My App is connected to Microsoft Access database, on IDE(target)environment it works good and Farsi font comes correctly, but when I run jar file in windows environment Farsi font comes like this ?????? or  ØºÙ„Ø§Ù
Access is 2013 
maybe problem is about Unicode but I don't know how to solve it
I didn't find any thing of Farsi font in Internationalization

Comment: We have no idea what kind of app you're talking about. Is this Swing? Something else? Have you looked at the data you're getting back in terms of its UTF-16 code units to check that *that's* okay? (You should be able to isolate it to just a display problem, which you could demonstrate with hard-coded strings, or just a database problem, which isn't really about the display part.)

Comment: Read http://www.digitalcitizen.life/changing-display-language-used-non-unicode-programs

Comment: My App is Swing and GUI

Comment: It is GUI application and also Swing, this problem happens during save and retrieve data from Access tables

Comment: My problem has solved by changing language in administrative tab, but one of alphabet (ی) still come like ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to find out which command line arguments that passed by IDE, You can do so either by inspecting IDE run parameters or with help of [Process Explorer](https://superuser.com/questions/415360/how-do-i-find-out-command-line-arguments-of-a-running-program).

For console applications almost all of encoding problems are solved by running `chcp 65001` preliminarily and by setting setting console font to `Lucida Console`

Answer (score 0):

by default windows uses Windows-1252 or CP-1252 encoding scheme; if you are running jar file through IDE that will works fine as IDE can use other system fonts that support that arguments language, but not console. If you are running jar file through console then it will so garbage data if that encoding isn't supported by console.

Right click on cmd title bar--> click property 
Switch to fonts tab and change from raster fonts to '[Lucida Console](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=1262)' or '[Consolas](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=1924)'; check unicode range in links.
if your farsi font comes in that range then it will get properly displayed.

or add '
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Console\TrueTypeFont'
new string value here with name = 00,000,0000... and value = font name